# Подскажите как сделать "путь пользователя"? Показать ему на какой он сейчас странице?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите библиотеки или пути решения отслеживания на какой странице сейчас пользователь? Показать ему его путь в виде `Главная > товары > бытовое > мелкое > фен такой то` и что бы все было ссылками.

Comment: Поищи в сети информацию на тему `хлебные крошки js`

Comment: [Ку здарова](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/breadcrumb/)